# sub eax,0 - does it do anything?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I just opened a file in IDA Pro and I found some code that looks completely useless. However, I thought it might have some use. Doesn't the `sub eax,0` just subtract 0 from eax?

The code:

```
hinstDLL= dword ptr  4  
fdwReason= dword ptr  8  
lpReserved= dword ptr  0Ch  

mov     eax, [esp+fdwReason]  
sub     eax, 0  
jz      short loc_10001038
```

Comment: Yes, it subtracts zero from eax. But that *does* do something, it sets the flags. For example, the only way it will result in zero, is if eax was zero to begin with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `sub` instruction sets flags (`OF`, `SF`, `ZF`, `AF`, `PF`, and `CF`, according to the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)) - the `mov` instruction does not.  The `jz` will jump only if the zero flag (`ZF`) is set, so if you want to jump based on the value in `eax` that flag has to be set appropriately.

Comment: I thought you needed to use the TEST instruction for that. Thanks!

Comment: `test` does do an implicit bitwise AND, but doesn't affect all of the same flags.  From the `test` docs: "The `OF` and `CF` flags are set to `0`. The `SF`, `ZF`, and `PF` flags are set according to the result... The state of the `AF` flag is undefined."

Answer (score 6):

The `sub` instruction will set the zero flag if its result is zero. In this case this means that the zero flag will be set if eax is zero.

So these three instructions check if `[esp+fdwReason]` is zero and jump to `loc_10001038` in that case.